# Helm iterate over string with comma separated values

Tags: for-loop, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'd like to iterate over string which contain comma separated values using range. For example:

`DNS_NAMES: example.com, example2.com, example3.com`

and then iterate using range over values: `example.com, example2.com, example3.com`

Comment: Where does the string come from?  Can you make it a YAML list instead?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `split`

---

values.yaml

```yaml
DNS_NAMES: example.com, example2.com, example3.com
```

templates/cm.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |-
    args:
    {{- range ( split ", " $.Values.DNS_NAMES ) }}
      - {{ . }}
    {{- end }}
```

output.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  config.yaml: |-
    args:
      - example.com
      - example2.com
      - example3.com
```